# GET request breaking due to '?' in the URL

Tags: javascript, api, url, curl

I am making a GET request and and I have to fill in a URL parameter except it contains question marks and is causing my request to break.

The docs say the request should look like this:

```
website.com/api?url=`INSERT+URL+HERE`
```

But the URL I am inserting has a `?` and cuts off `more+values` in the request:

```
url = myurl.com/example?more+values
```

Is there anyway in Javascript to ignore all params after `?`

I have searched everywhere and cant seem to do it. Please do not suggest posting in the body.

Comment: Call `encodeURIComponent()` on your query string parameter.

Comment: perfect, thanks @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on your query string parameter:

```js
let value = encodeURIComponent('myurl.com/example?more+values');
let url = 'website.com/api?url=' + value;

console.log(url);
```